# How to fix "free variable 'db_username' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope"

Tags: tkinter, python-3.7, pymysql

ive just started learning python and im great at making programs without GUI's but ive been working with them and without tkinter my pymysql code works just fine but when i started playing with tkinter it wasnt working like it did without it i keep getting referenced before assignment no matter how many different formats\organizations ive tried it still wont work heres the full code " https://pastebin.com/04uFWB1R "

like i said it works just fine without a gui but as soon as i try it with a gui it wont work

```
def lClick():
    __uID = uID.get()
    __uName = uName.get()
    __passW = passW.get()
    print(__uName)
    print(__passW)
    auth = Label(lWindow, text="Authorizing...",font=("Areial Bold", 10))
    auth.place(x=-10,y=99)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(1)
    def authorize():
        if __uID == "01":
            auth.configure(text='''
            User Authenticated...
            Accessing Database
            ''')
        ##############################################################
            def dbCon():
                con = pymysql.connect(host='192.***.***.**',
                    user='****',
                    password='******',
                    db='python1',
                    charset='utf8mb4',
                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
                with con:
                    cur = con.cursor()
                    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'id' = '{0}'".format(__uID))
                    rows = cur.fetchall()
                    for row in rows:
                        db_username = row['username']
                        db_password = row['password']
                def logon():
                    if __uName == db_username:
                        auth.configure(text="DataBase Connected")
                    else:
                        auth.configure(text="Error Has Occured")
                logon()
            dbCon()
        else:
            auth.configure(text="Not Authorized")
    authorize()
```

im trying to figure out how to fix the "variable referenced before assignment" error

Comment: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'id' = '{0}'".format(__uID)) the problem was the ' ' around the 'id' = '{0}' it should be id = {0}

Comment: The cause of the exception is that `db_username` will not be created if the query returns no record and the line `if __uName == db_username:` in `logon()` will raise such exception.